# Handling old data in new app versions in ANDROID...!

Tags: android

Handling old data in new app versions,

e.g.: in Internal or External storage's data, if I changed some App's generated folder's name then data would we copied into new folder.

For databases you can use the built in SQLiteOpenHelper class it has the onUpgrade method.

Is there any to do for Internal or External storage's data ???

thanks...!

Answer (score 0):

Its not that easy to do that as with SQLite.

You need to do many things

- Have an Preference to store the Current Version.
- Have One method or class for each Version.
- Implement your own Application Class for updating

**Your Method or Class for each Version**

Here you need to modified the data in either storage to the latest version.

**Own Application**

In your own Application class you need to check whether Current Version (stored in preference) is the latest version.

If not then you need to call corresponding method or class which do the conversion.

Hope this gives you an idea.